# ValueError when using scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, scipy, integral, quad

I am receiving a `ValueError` when integrating using `scipy.integrate.quad`. Here is my simplified code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
p = np.arange(0,1,1/1000)
h = lambda p: p**2/2+p*(1-p)
Kl = lambda p: h(p) + 0.02
K = Kl(p)
R = 0.5*h(p) + 0.5*h(1)
Vl = lambda p: np.minimum.reduce([p, K, R])
integrate.quad(Vl, 0, 1)[0]
```

The last line gives the exception:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can someone please propose how to do this integration properly? Thanks

Comment: Could you explain your `Vl` function?  What do you want `np.minimum.reduce([p, K, R])` to do?

Comment: Thanks @DSM. I would like it to take the element-wise minimum of p, K and R. I think of it as a mathematical function Vl(p,K(p),R(p))

Comment: This is the same code as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342409/valueerror-when-defining-a-lambda-function-in-python; just a slightly different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code confuses functions on floats with arrays.  The function argument to `quad` needs to accept a float and return a float.  In

```
Vl = lambda p: np.minimum.reduce([p, K, R])
```

`p` is a float (and is not the `p` array-- it's usually a bad idea to have a module global with the same name as an argument) and `K` and `R` are arrays, which isn't what we want (that's what's throwing the error.)

I think you're just looking for

```
def h(p):
    return p**2/2+p*(1-p)

def K(p):
    return h(p) + 0.02

def R(p):
    return 0.5*h(p) + 0.5*h(1)

def Vl(p):
    return min(p, K(p), R(p))
```

which gives me

```
In [177]: integrate.quad(Vl, 0, 1.0)
Out[177]: (0.34689543041336846, 4.8736376714649885e-09)
```